# Как спарсить страницу google

Tags: парсер

При попытке парсинга страницы google через `file_get_contents()` она выглядит не так как должна:

[image: Результат парсинга через file_get_contents()]

Как добиться результата один в один с оригиналом?
Нужно вот так:

[image: Оригинал]

Comment: Открывать с помощью настоящего браузера

Comment: попробуйте сделать полноценный курл с заголовками